# How to implement transactional request with RoboSpice

Tags: android, robospice

I have a problem handling transactional request. Says request A has a dependency on the result of request B and request C. I'd like to put all A, B and C into the request queue of a SpiceService. In this way, task will be easy keeping requests running in background.

My current implementation is handling request B, C, collecting their response, then, from Activity, start request A with data obtained from request B and C. But when the activity is paused, request A will never be pushed to the request queue. (Request A will be pushed to the request queue once the Activity comes back and check state of request B and C using `addListenerIfPending` and `getDataFromCache`)

Another idea is to implement a Service that takes responsibility of issuing requests to SpiceService instead of Activity. But it's a little bit complex.

The ideal solution to the problem may be implement a nested request, that is, push request A, B and C into request queue and have request A listen to data from request B and C. But this require access to something like SpiceManager from a SpiceRequest running on a thread managed by SpiceService. I'm wondering if there be any any problem using RS in this way.

And another problem is that request A will be blocking waiting for a completion signal from request B and C. Is there any SpiceRequest implementation that implements `loadDataFromNetwork()` in asynchronous approach?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, such scenario ("run B and C in parallel, and then run A") should be a single peace of work (`SpiceRequest`) from Robospice's perspective. I'd just create my own `SpiceRequest` implementation that runs multiple network requests in its `loadDataFromNetwork()` method. It can spawn additional threads inside this method to run B and C requests in parallel.

There is another nice library which can help you handle dependenices between asynchronous "tasks" called Bolts-Android (https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android).

Here is how I used it to run two tasks in parallel and wait for their completion:

```
List<Task<Void>> tasks = new LinkedList<Task<Void>>();
tasks.add(Task.call(new Callable<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        //do task a
    }

}));
tasks.add(Task.call(new Callable<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        //do task b
    }
}));
Task.whenAll(tasks).waitForCompletion();
```